# TQDM by percentage

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

how can I make a progress bar with a percentage like this:

```py
with tqdm_gui(total=100) as pbar:
    if percentage == 10:
        pbar.update(10)
            # [...]
```

Comment: What does not work as you want?

Comment: Also what does `tkinter` tag has to do with `tgdm` question (i.e. terminal progress bar)?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. You have to better describe problem - we can't read in your mind.

Comment: Do you want to set value exactly `percentage` instead of adding `percentage` to current value? Yesterday was question about `tqdm` and maybe you have the same problem. If you want to set directly some value then you may need `pbar.n = value` and `pbar.refresh()`